# MVC3: How do I bind a model that contains a generic list of a certain class back to the controller? It always is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

## The Situation

Within the BuyerOtherInfoModel there is a generic list of BuyerPropertyInfoModels which is called LinkedProperties. When I load my view the editor template iterates through this generic list and works great. But when I postback I have issues with null values.

## My Problem

My model binds to the view initially perfectly but when I postback the LinkedProperties generic list is always null. How do I make my editortemplate / jquery template match up correctly on postback? Sorry if this is hard to explain please ask for clarification.

## Pastes:

Model: http://pastebin.com/UemmdqSg 
Editor Template: http://pastebin.com/2v0fxgiq

Sorry guys this is my first question on stackoverflow and I have attempted to search for this problem already but I have no clue where to go from here. Let me know if you need any clarification on the issue. Thanks alot!

Comment: Where is your form declaration?  Your view should be wrapped in a `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { .... }`

Comment: Yes everything is wrapped but my form is huge, the  area in which i call the editor is at http://pastebin.com/byWn2z9H

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Okay guys so I figured it out, I was attempting to use an editortemplate and a @Html.EditorFor for rendering...but when I manually pasted the template into my view and posted back the List of objects is no longer null and works correctly. The question now is how would i get a List of complex objects to bind back to the controller if they are nested inside an editortemplate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor for BuyerListModel:

```
public class BuyerListModel {
    public int FirstItemOnPage { get; set; }
    // ...
    public PagedList<BuyListItem> ListItems { get; set; }

    public BuyerListModel() {
        // When it attempts to put the BuyListItems into the collection,
        // The parameter isn't initialized, so it's internally catching
        // a null reference exception.
        ListItems = new PagedList<BuyListItem>();
    }
}
```